# Ошибка в c++, использована не инициализированная переменная element

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я только начал изучать этот прекрасный язык, и у меня возникла идея сделать программу, которая будет переводить любое число из трех систем счисления в 10, но у меня аозникла ошибка, что использована не инициализирована переменная в 13 строке, вот код :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


char reform_number(int number, int exit_sys)
{
    char finally_number[40];
    int element;

        if (exit_sys == 2)
        {
            while ((number / 2) > 2)
            {
                element = element + number % 2;
                number = number / 2 - number % 2;
            }
        }
        if (exit_sys == 8)
        { 
            while ((number % 8) > 8)
            {
                element = element + number % 8;
                number = number / 8 - number % 8;
            }
        }
        if (exit_sys == 16)
        {
            while ((number % 16) > 16)
            {
                element = element + number % 16;
                number = number / 16 - number % 16;
            }
        }
    return finally_number[40];
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    int exit_sys;
    char exit[10];
    int finally_number;

    while (exit != "exit")
    {
        cout << "Write your number in 10 math sys.\n\t";
        cin >> number;

        cout << "Write exit math system for " << number << "\n\t";
        cin >> exit_sys;

        finally_number = reform_number(number, exit_sys);
        cout << "good, your number is  " << finally_number << "\n";

        cout << "Are you need to restart? (y/n)\n\t";
        cin >> exit;

        if (exit == "y") continue;
        else break;

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Если что, я пока сам не особо понял как составить данный процесс, но хотелось бы чтобы никакие библиотеки не использовались, и все было в обычной форме

Comment: А вы понимаете, что вам компилятор написал? Что значит "неинициализированная"?

Comment: Если честно, то нет)

Comment: Воот. Надо сначала понять смысл слов, которые вы видите, а потом разбираться с проблемой. "Инициализировать" - значит установить начальное значение. Для `element` вы не установили никакое значение перед тем, как ее значение использовать.

Answer (score 2):

```
int element;
```

Тут Вы объявили переменную, но не инициализирует, т.е в ней какой-то мусор.

Ниже вы используете ее для расчетов, что приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Вероятно, Вам необходим 0?

```
int element = 0;
```

И вообще, зачем тут эта переменная, если она ни на что не влияет?
Так же как и finally_number никак не меняется, но Вы возвращаете ее из функции. Возможно, должен быть возвращен element?

Comment: В том то и проблема, что пока я не очень разобрался как это устроить, а тут еще и ошика наскочила